# Was this line in the original Pierre Boulle book?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes

> Take your stinking paws off me, you damn dirty ape!

Was this in the original Pierre Boulle's book or did someone invent it for the movie? Mr Heston perhaps?

> Taylor escapes and during his desperate flight through Ape City finds himself in a museum, where Dodge's stuffed and eyeless corpse is now on display. When Taylor is recaptured by gorillas, his voice has recovered enough to growl, "Take your stinking paws off me, you damn dirty ape!"

<sup>[Planet of the Apes (1968)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes_(1968_film))</sup>

Comment: Just curious, it was on TV today

Comment: Of interest - http://www.rodserling.com/pota.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not in the book, at least not in the English edition I read.

Comment: It's not in the French version either, as far as I can tell.